# preg_replace problem

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'd like to match and extract variables from: `{{variable:int}}`

- **variable** would be anything a-z
- **:** is a separator
- **int** would be an integer 0-9

Curretly i have: `preg_replace('!\{\{(\S+)\}\}!', "$1", $string)`
which does only half the job, i still have to split by `:`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the name/value, I think you want to use preg_match.

```
preg_match('!\{\{(.*?):(\d)\}\}!', $string, $matches);  
$varname = $matches[1];  
$val = $matches[2];
```

Comment: Suited my needs best. Thank you all for replying!

Answer (score 2):

You need a [non-greedy](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) match (`.*?`): `preg_replace('!\{\{(.*?):(\d)\}\}!')`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
{{([a-zA-Z]+):(\d+)}}
```

$1 will contain the captured variable, $2 will contain the captured integer

**Explanation**

```
{{([a-zA-Z])+:(\d+)}}
```

[a-zA-Z]+ means atleast one more alphabets (small or caps)
followed by a ":"
followed by atleast one or more digits (0-9)